# regex with multiple group swift

Tags: swift, regex, swift4

im using swift 4 and got some problems with regex captured group.

so , i have regex here :

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:"Tambah saldo via (merchant|transfer (online|bank)).(\\w+ \\.?)($)?(((\\w+\\.)?\\w+? (\\w+ )?\\.) No Rek:([0-9]+(.[0-9])*).[^0-9]+([0-9]+))?", options: .caseInsensitive)
```

and has multiple response :

```
let response1 = "Tambah saldo via transfer bank BCA PT.BARRYPRIMA CORP . No Rek:427.123.444 . Jumlah transfer Rp.200864."
let response2 = "Tambah saldo via transfer online Bersama BARRYPRIMA CORP . No Rek:123456. Jumlah transfer Rp.200864."
let response3 = "Tambah saldo via transfer bank Mandiri BARRYPRIMA . No Rek:43512343598347. Jumlah transfer Rp.200864."
let response4 = "Tambah saldo via merchant Tito ."
let response5 = "Tambah saldo via merchant Bagaskara putra."
```

i want to get multiple values and store it to [String] the value im looking is

> 1: "transfer bank" , "BCA" , "PT.BARRYPRIMA CORP","427.123.444","200864"
>
> 2: "transfer online", "Bersama", "BARRYPRIMA CORP", "123456","200864"
>
> 3: "transfer bank" , "Mandiri" , "BARRYPRIMA","43512343598347","200864"
>
> 4: "merchant","tito"
>
> 5: "merchant","bagaskara putra"

i ve tried function from [this one](https://samwize.com/2016/07/21/how-to-capture-multiple-groups-in-a-regex-with-swift/)

and get this errors

> Thread 1: Fatal error: subscript: subrange extends past String end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to modify your regex pattern, to get the expected captures you describe.

- Suppress some captures by using `(?:...)`
- Your pattern has some faults, for example `([0-9]+(.[0-9])*)` does not match `427.123.444`

I got this:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:"Tambah saldo via (merchant|transfer (?:online|bank)).(?:(\\w+(?:\\s*\\w+)*)\\.$|(\\w+)\\s+)(?:(?:((?:\\w+\\.)?\\w+?(?:\\s+\\w+)?)\\s+\\.) No Rek:([0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)*)\\s*\\.[^0-9]+([0-9]+))?", options: .caseInsensitive)
```

But you may need to modify some more parts, because I do not understand how `.` or  works.

And I do not understand why this input:

```
let response5 = "Tambah saldo via merchant Bagaskara putra."
```

generates:

> ```
> 5: "merchant","bagaskara putra"
> ```

Isn't it "merchant", "Bagaskara", "putra" ? (3-elements I mean.)

---

But your question is about how to return multiple captures into a String Array, not about finding the right pattern for your purpose.

So, I use the regex above for testing.

---

The reason why you get **Fatal error: subscript: subrange extends past String end** is because some capture groups may return `NSRange(location: NSNotFound, length: 0)` when not matched. (`NSNotFound` is a huge Int.)

This happens when the capture group is included in some optional pattern using `?` or `|`.

We can use `Range(nsRange, in: str)` when converting `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>`, which returns `nil` (not crashes!) in such cases.

So, you can write something like this:

```
extension String {
    func capturedGroups(withRegex regex: NSRegularExpression) -> [String] {
        guard let match = regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<utf16.count)) else {
            return []
        }

        let lastRangeIndex = match.numberOfRanges - 1
        guard lastRangeIndex >= 1 else { return [] }

        return (1...lastRangeIndex).compactMap {Range(match.range(at: $0), in: self)}
            .map {String(self[$0])}
    }
}
```

With using the extension above, you can get these outputs:

```
let response1 = "Tambah saldo via transfer bank BCA PT.BARRYPRIMA CORP . No Rek:427.123.444 . Jumlah transfer Rp.200864."
let response2 = "Tambah saldo via transfer online Bersama BARRYPRIMA CORP . No Rek:123456. Jumlah transfer Rp.200864."
let response3 = "Tambah saldo via transfer bank Mandiri BARRYPRIMA . No Rek:43512343598347. Jumlah transfer Rp.200864."
let response4 = "Tambah saldo via merchant Tito ."
let response5 = "Tambah saldo via merchant Bagaskara putra."
[response1, response2, response3, response4, response5].forEach { str in
    print(str.capturedGroups(withRegex: regex))
}
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ["transfer bank", "BCA", "PT.BARRYPRIMA CORP", "427.123.444", "200864"]
> ["transfer online", "Bersama", "BARRYPRIMA CORP", "123456", "200864"]
> ["transfer bank", "Mandiri", "BARRYPRIMA", "43512343598347", "200864"]
> ["merchant", "Tito"]
> ["merchant", "Bagaskara putra"]
> ```